# Terraform attach disks dynamic

Tags: terraform

Point: I need to dynamically attach disks created with a for_each loop to VM

```
resource "yandex_compute_disk" "volume" {
  for_each = var.volumes
  name     = each.value["name"]
  size     = each.value["size"]
  type     = each.value["type"]
```

```
resource "yandex_compute_instance" "vps" {
  count       = var.server_count
  name        = var.server_count > 1 ? "${var.server_name}${count.index}" : var.server_name
  platform_id = var.platform_id
  zone        = var.zone
....
....
....
  dynamic "secondary_disk" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      disk_id     = yandex_compute_disk.volume.id -- here is problem
      auto_delete = var.server_volume_auto_delete
    }
  }
```

error:

````
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     yandex_compute_disk.volume[each.key]```
````

But its not work like that `yandex_compute_disk.volume[each.key].id`

Comment: Wait, so that is a self reference? Or you are just omitting other resources instead of adding them all?

Comment: @MarkoE its 2 different resources. i edit post

Comment: Are you sure that the `yandex_compute_disk` resource exports an attribute named `id`? Because I am looking at the documentation and I don't see that attribute.

Comment: @MarkoE absolutely

Comment: I tried to answer, but there might be some additional things that might be needed in the question if the answer does not work. For example, values for the `volumes` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requested attribute is being exported, then this might work:

```
resource "yandex_compute_instance" "vps" {
  count       = var.server_count
  name        = var.server_count > 1 ? "${var.server_name}${count.index}" : var.server_name
  platform_id = var.platform_id
  zone        = var.zone
....
....
....
  dynamic "secondary_disk" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      disk_id     = yandex_compute_disk.volume[secondary_disk.name].id
      auto_delete = var.server_volume_auto_delete
    }
  }
```

The important thing to note about using `dynamic` blocks is the iterator [1] name. If you do not set it, it will default to the label of the dynamic block, i.e., `secondary_disk` in this case. At a very high level, you could say that iterator name replaces the `each` object.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks